# Scrapy referer None

Tags: python, scrapy

Hello i'm trying to scrape yellowpages canada using scrapy this is my spider code:

```
import scrapy


class YellSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yellspider'

    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/40/dentist/Toronto+ON']

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = ['http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{0}/dentist/Toronto+ON'.format(x) for x in xrange(1, 51)]
        for u in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=u, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.css(".listing.listing--bottomcta.placement"):
            yield {
                'name': job.css(".listing__name--link::text").extract_first(),
                'street': job.css(".jsMapBubbleAddress:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
                'locality': job.css(".jsMapBubbleAddress:nth-child(2)::text").extract_first(),
                'postalCode': job.css(".jsMapBubbleAddress:nth-child(4)::text").extract_first(),
                'website': job.css(".mlr__item.mlr__item--website a::attr(href)").re(r'\?(.*)'),
                'phone': job.css(".mlr__submenu__item h4::text").extract_first(default='no phone number')
            }
```

for instance i know that search result has exactly 50 pages so i did create a url list using list comprehension. 
than i used css selectors to look for the content that i want to scrape.

now let's dig into the **problem** :

everything works fine until i reach the pages [28 to 50] this is how the output looks like

[click here to see the output image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=32298254az.jpg)

**PS**: i did change the **USER_AGENT** i did also add a **DOWNLOAD_DELAY =3** and also tried to add **referer** to the headers but nothing worked

something else to mention is that in the scrapy shell selectors works fine for rest of pages [28 to 50]

Answer (score 1):

check out page 28 or 29. I had a similar issue with a project I did. When I looked at the pages that were not working I noticed that the page layout was different for those pages and the xpaths I was using didn't exist on those pages. Maybe the css on pages 28-50 are different then pages 1-27.

Comment: Yes i double checked that they were different

Answer (score 0):

First you should import library:

```
import re
```

Then, for link a `href` you don't have extraction `.extract()` instead you added `re`.
To debug - try first to pull full a `href` with `extract()` function just to get it work - than you will easy do `regex` on exported link.